# On an alternative definition of addition, $S(a)\ +'\ S(b) = S(a\ +'\ (b\ +'\ 1))$, assuming the first nine Peano axioms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, peano-axioms

Full disclaimer: I have edited the question to make it simpler, and therefore some of the comments may no longer make much sense.

Assume we have defined the set $\mathbb{N}$ using the first nine [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Historical_second-order_formulation). For brevity, $1$ is defined as $S(0),\ 2\ $ is defined as $S(1),\ $ etc.

Define the function, $+': (\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}) \times (\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\})\to (\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}) $ recursively by:

- $0\ +'\ a=a\qquad (1)$
- $S(a)\ +'\ S(b) = S(a\ +'(\ b\ +'\ 1)\ )\qquad (2)$

So for example,

$1\ +'\ 1\ \overset{def}{=}\ S(0)\ +'\ S(0) \overset{(2)}{=}\ S( 0\ +'\ (0\ +'\ 1)\ ) \overset{(1)}{=}\ S(0\ +'\ 1) \overset{(1)}{=}\ S(1) \overset{def}{=} 2. $

And I believe we can prove all other additions match our expectations using similar reasoning.

> Edit: I don't see how we show that $\ 1\ +'\ 0 = 1.$

I *think* this is an alternative way of [defining addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Defining_arithmetic_operations_and_relations).

Is this correct? Does my definition of addition give us the expected results and therefore also match wikipedia's definition?

Comment: Where have you defined the term $a+''b+''1$ that is used in ($2\ast$)?

Comment: Actually, don't you need to define $1$ in order to use it for both $+'$ and $+''$?

Comment: You haven't defined $+''1.$

Comment: I'd try to prove $0+'' a =a$ in your definition.

Comment: Isn’t $1$ defined as $S(0)$ in the Peano axioms ?

Comment: I think Wikipedia's is wrong, too, or you have misread it, though. In fact, all you need to define addition is: $(1)\,a+'0=a,$ and $(2)\,a+S(b)=S(a+b).$ The associate property can be proved from these two.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I’m confused by your comment because what you have written *is* wikipedia’s definition of addition. And just because you can prove it from those two axioms doesn’t answer my question.

Comment: Fundamentally, you are confusing "definition" with axioms. While the definitions of addition and multiplication in first order logic are, indeed, also axioms, they are axioms which make clear *how* to compute addition in the cases we intuit are part of the natural numbers. It is a recursive definition of addition (and doesn't include the associative law, since that can be proven.) The "definition" you've given doesn't tell us how to compute $0+a,$ and the associative law is not part of a recursive definition, merely assertion of a property of addition. I wouldn't call yours a definition.

Comment: @AdamRubinson No, it isn't the same as Wikipedia. You are using $x+'1$ and $x+''1$ as synonyms for $S(x),$ but that requires a definition. It's easy to derive on Wikipedia's definition, but not so easy in your definition.

Comment: Wikipedia only says $a+0=0$ and $a+S(b)=S(a+b).$ There is no instance of $S(a).$

Comment: So $$2+2=2+S(S(0))=S(2+S(0))-=S(S(2+0))=S(S(2))=S(3)=4.$$ We never have to recurse on $a,$ just $b.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews "The "definition" you've given doesn't tell us how to compute  0+a". You're right I shouldn't have called it a "definition", maybe, "possible definition" is better. My question is, essentially: *Can you prove that it isn't a definition that is equivalent to the usual definition of addition (from wikipedia)?*

Comment: It's never a definition if you are asserting a fact about it that isn't definitional. Even if you prove these conditions are equivalent to the standard "definition," your conditions are not a definition. Mind you, again, in first order logic, there isn't a real notion of defining a function, but here I am using the word "definition" computationally - do the axioms tell you how to compute $+?$ You haven't said how to compute $0+a$ under your axioms.

Comment: Is the definition of $1$ not $S(0)$ ? I thought we don't need the definition of addition to help define $1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews does the question make more sense now?

Comment: You still cant tell us how to compute $2+0.$

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I have in my notes that we can get $1+'0=0,$ but I don't see how, so maybe that note is wrong. But for $a\geq 0,b\geq 1,\ $ we do get the usual addition: $a +' b = a+b.$ So for example, we do get $2+'3 = 5.$ To get $1 +' 0 = 0,\ $ we would need another axiom... I guess this answers the question?

Comment: You need another axiom, but it needs to cover a lot of cases. I think $a +' 0 =a$ would suffice. You need at least that much because you have to define not only $1+'0$ but also $2+'0,$ $3+'0,$ and so forth, from which you can then get $2+'1,$ and $3+'2,$ for example. Your two axioms only define $a+b$ when $b \geq a.$

Answer (score 1):

Given the two axioms in the question, we can deduce that $a\ +'\ b = a+b\ $ for all $a$ and all $b\geq 1.$

However, I don't see a reason why $1\ +'\ 0$ cannot equal any natural number (or zero).

Same for $a\ +'\ 0$ for any $a:\ $ it can be equal to any natural number and this doesn't lead to contradictions, e.g. by the pigeonhole principle.

Obviously there are many ways a third axiom would give us $a\ +'\ 0 = a\quad \forall a,\ $ for example associativity:

$ a\ +'\ (b\ +'\ c) = (a\ +'\ b)\ +'\ c\quad \forall\ a,b,c $

This would work because, for example:

$S(1)\ +'\ S(0) = S(1\ +'\ (0\ +'\ 1)) = S(2) = S((1\ +'\ 0)\ +'\ 1)\implies\ 1\ +'\ 0 = 1,\ $ because $+': (\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}) \times (\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\})\to (\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}) $ is a function and the only value of $k$ for which $k\ +'\ 1 = 2\ $ is $\ k=1.$

Commutativity is an alternative third axiom that would make the usual addition work for all $a,b$ because along with axiom $(1)$ we would have: $a\ +'\ 0=0\quad \forall a.$

Comment: The first sentence still is not quite correct. "All $a$ and all $b\geq1$" makes the claim that $3+'2=3+2=5,$ but $3+'2$ only has to be $(1+'0)+4,$ and as you say, $1+'0$ could be anything.

Comment: With regards to my first sentence and speaking about the two axioms in the question: "But $3\ +'\ 2\ $ only has to be $(1\ +'\ 0)\ +'\ 4.$" No, I don't think my claim that $ a\ +'\ b = a+b\ $ for all $a$ and all $b\geq 1$ implies that $(1\ +' 0)\ +'\ 4 = 5.$ And yes, I agree that $1\ +'\ 0$ could be anything and therefore $(1\ +' 0)\ +'\ 4$ could be anything. So I'm not quite sure what you're saying...

Comment: You said you could deduce that $a+'b = a+b$ for all $a$ and all $b\geq 1.$ That includes for $a=3$ and $b=2.$ Do you still think you can deduce that $a+'b = a+b$ for $a=3$ and $b=2$? Have you tried proving it?

Comment: Yes. $3\ +'\ 2 = S(2)\ +'\ S(1) = S(2\ +'\ (1\ +'\ 1)) = S(2\ +'\ 2) = S(4) = 5.$

Comment: Ah, ok. So the reason you need an extra axiom for $a+'0$ is because $0$ is not a successor of any number.

Comment: Essentially, yes....